# how to find eigenvalues of $T_n:R^n\to R^n$ where $T_n (x)=(0,x_1,\frac{x_2}{2},\ldots,\frac{x_{n-1}}{n-1})$, what happen if $n\to\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

how to find eigenvalues of $T_n:R^n\to R^n$ where $T_n (x)=(0,x_1,\frac{x_2}{2},\ldots,\frac{x_{n-1}}{n-1})$  what happen if $n\to\infty$, well by definition i do $T_n(x)=\lambda x$ hence

$(0,x_1,\frac{x_2}{2},\ldots,\frac{x_{n-1}}{n-1})=(\lambda x_1,\ldots,\lambda x_n)$ imply

$0=\lambda x_1=\lambda^2 x_2=2\lambda^3 x_3=\ldots =(n-1)!\lambda^n x_n $ so i think that $\lambda$ have to be zero right? and when $n\to\infty$ the operator $T_n$ go to  null operator right? i will apreciate any hint please

Comment: It will *not* go to the null operator, for example $T(1,0,\ldots)=(0,1,0,\ldots)$ even as $n\to\infty$. What you found is that $T$ would have the zero eigenvalue only. But so does $T_n$, right?

Comment: thank you, is true, but how to prove the only eigenvalues is $0$ please?

Comment: Hint: $T_n^n=0$ so $T_n$ can have $0$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "what happens if $n \to ∞$". All $T_n$ have different domains and ranges, so do you want to consider some $T_\infty$? In that case you have to specify domaim and range of $T_\infty$, There are various possible choices.

Comment: Note that the matrix representation of $T_n$ with respect to the standard basis is strictly lower triangular, and so, the only eigenvalue of $T_n$ is zero. But a reasonable candidate for the limit of $T_n$ would be the integral operator $$Tf(x):=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$ (by identifying $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the space of polynomials with degree $<n$). Its well-definedness as well as other properties will depend on how we choose the space on which this operator lives.

Comment: thank you everyone, Well the excercise is be in Kreyszig book, just ask what happen when $n\to\infty$, besides If $(T_n)^n$ has $0$ the only eigenvalue, imply $0$ is the only eigenvalue? Can you be more specific please

Comment: If your book discusses norms and Hilbert or Banach spaces it makes sense to ask about the limiting case. Otherwise, not really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that $0$ is an eigenvalue because $T_n(x) = 0$ iff $x_1 = \ldots = x_{n-1} = 0$. Thus all $(0,\ldots,0,x_n)$ with $x_n \ne 0$ are eigenvectors.

No $\lambda \ne 0$ can be an eigenvalue because then $0=\lambda x_1=\lambda^2 x_2=2\lambda^3 x_3=\ldots =(n-1)!\lambda^n x_n $ implies that $x = 0$.

An alternative way to see this is decribed in Thomas Andrews' comment. We have $(T_n)^n = 0$. If $T_n$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda \ne 0$, then we can take an eigenvector $x \ne 0$ and get $(T_n)^n(x) = \lambda^n x \ne 0$.

**Edited:**

It is not clear what is meant by $n \to \infty$. There are many possible interpretations, here is one:

Let $\mathbb R^\infty$ denote the vector space of all real sequences $(x_n)$. Define $T_\infty : \mathbb R^\infty \to \mathbb R^\infty, T_\infty(x_1,x_2,\ldots) = (0,x_1,\frac{x_2}{2},\ldots,\frac{x_{n-1}}{n-1},\ldots)$. This map does not have eigenvalues. In fact, it is injective which means that $0$ is no eigenvalue. No $\lambda \ne 0$ can be an eigenvalue because $T_\infty(x) = \lambda x$ implies $0=(n-1)!\lambda^n x_n $ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. This means $x = 0$.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: and what happen with the limit when $n\to \infty$ please

Comment: As I said in my above comment, you have to explain what the limit operator should be. Otherwise no answer is possible.

Comment: well i read your comment above, depend of the domain of $T_{\infty}$ right? but the book don be specific, which domain and rang your choose please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $T^n = 0$ so by the spectral mapping theorem we have
$$\sigma(T)^n = \sigma(T^n) = \{0\} \implies \sigma(T) = \{0\}$$
so $0$ is the only eigenvalue.

For the case $n\to \infty$, have a look at $\ell^\infty$, the space of all bounded sequences equipped with the supremum norm $\|(x_n)_n\|_\infty= \sup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}|x_n|$. Then we can look at $T : \ell^\infty \to \ell^\infty$ given by
$$T(x_1,x_2,x_3, \ldots) = \left(0,x_1,\frac{x_2}{2},\ldots,\frac{x_{k-1}}{k-1},\ldots\right).$$

Notice that $T^n$ acts as
$$T^n(x_1,x_2,x_3, \ldots) = \left(\underbrace{0,\ldots, 0}_{n}, \frac{x_1}{1\cdot 2 \cdots  n},\frac{x_2}{2\cdot 3 \cdots  (n+1)},\ldots,\frac{x_{k-1}}{(k-1)\cdot k \cdots (k-1+n)},\ldots\right)$$
so
$$\|T^n(x_n)_n\|_\infty = \sup_{k\in\Bbb{N}} \frac{|x_{k-1}|}{(k-1)\cdot k \cdots (k-1+n)} \le \frac1{n!} \sup_{k\in\Bbb{N}}|x_k| = \frac1{n!}\|x\|_\infty$$
and therefore $\|T^n\| \le \frac1{n!}$. We have a formula for spectral radius:
$$\sup_{\lambda \in \sigma(T)} |\lambda| = r(T) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \|T^n\|^{\frac1n} \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{\sqrt[n]{n!}} = 0$$
so again $\sigma(T) = \{0\}$.

Comment: thank you, do you know what to say for the second question, i mean what happen if $n\to\infty$, well i think that $n$ has variation just in $T_n$

Comment: @weymarandres Have a look now, hope you understand this.